# Why is my footer missing

Tags: php, footer

Hi for some reason my footer is missing on my site, and i don't know why. I have deactivated all plugins and it's still not there, I have checked the css and all, but the footer is still missing can someone tell me whats wrong.

When I view the Source Code the Footer is there but It's not showing up.

The Site is EricaVain.com

Here are the files on gist --> https://gist.github.com/mihadaiko/5008645

Comment: Can you provide any code or link. We really can't tell you why it's not there unless we can SEE your code. It sounds like either a css issue or you're not calling `wp_footer();` correctly. If it's in the source code my guess is you're not closing a div correctly. Is is gone on ALL pages or just some?

Comment: @BrandonRandon question updated

Comment: @brasofilo question updates

Comment: Glad you got the help you needed, but this question isn't a good fit for the site since it won't help future visitors. Closing for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your iframe tag that supplies your Facebook information isn't closed. So the code stops rendering from that tag on.

Comment: We all do idiotic things every once in a while. Good luck!

Comment: Donnow if break things or not, but many duplicated ID's and other errors: [validator.w3.org](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2FEricaVain.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)